# Change the Default Plugin page filter to Active intead of All

Tags: hooks

Thanks in advance to all,

is there a way to change the default filter in the plugins page that is set
to `All` to something else like `Active` ? I'v tried to find a hook, but couldn't find any info.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no WordPress hook to filter the current status on the plugins admin, but if you must, you can use `$_REQUEST['plugin_status']` to change the default status.

See example below where I use the `load-plugins.php` hook to ensure we're changing the status (or modifying the superglobal `$_REQUEST`) only on the `plugins.php` page:

```php
function wpse_373622() {
    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['plugin_status'] ) ) {
        $_REQUEST['plugin_status'] = 'active';
    }
}
add_action( 'load-plugins.php', 'wpse_373622' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much worked like a charm